# Solution of this partial differential equation (with D'Alembertian)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm working on a paper about General Relativity and I am stuck in proving this result. I have this PDE:

$$\Box\phi = \frac{4m}{r^3}$$

Where $m$ is a positive parameter (basically, the mass), and $r$ is a generic spatial coordinate. Treat it as if it were $x$ or $y$ or whatever.

By consequence, the D'Alembertian operator is $\Box = \Box(r, t)$, and what I have is basically a non homogeneous wave equation.

I have the solution of this, which is

$$\phi = at + \log\left(1 - \frac{2m}{r}\right)  + A\left(r + 2m\log(r - 2m)\right) + B$$

Where $a, A, B$ are constants.

Any hint? Or any reference in which I might learn a bit about solving D'Alembertian non homogeneous equations?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the $3D$ Klein-Gordon equation? Which is linear?

Comment: @Mattos mmm no. Klein Gordon equation is $(\Box + m^2)\phi = 0$ (the homogeneous one), whilst here the $m^2\phi$ term is missing, and in exchange there is a non homogeneous term. In any case, are you suggesting me to try with Green's functions? Because I did. But I failed -.-

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the [Klein-Gordon in a potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein–Gordon_equation#Klein.E2.80.93Gordon_equation_in_a_potential). I'll have a look at the problem tonight when I get a chance. But the D'Alembertian operator is linear, so I would have thought that the linear methods would work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $\square$ isn't just the normal Minkowski-space d'Alembertian here. Otherwise why would the solution have a singularity at $r = 2m$? This type of behaviour is what we get when we have a horizon in our spacetime like for example in Schwarzschild.

Comment: If $f(r) = 1 - \frac{2m}{r}$ then the quoted $\phi$ is a solution to $-\frac{d}{dr}\left[f(r)\frac{d\phi}{dr}\right] = \frac{4m}{r^3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
For convenience, we will set $c=1$. Let us begin by rewriting the inhomogeneous wave equation in spherical coordinates to get
\begin{align}
\Box \phi = \left(\partial_{tt}-\partial_{rr}-\frac{2}{r}\partial_r+\text{ terms involving angular derivatives}\right)\phi = f(r).
\end{align}

To simplify matter, we will only look at radial solutions. Thus, our equation becomes
\begin{align}
\partial_{tt}\phi - \frac{2}{r}\partial_{r}\phi -\partial_{rr}\phi = f(r) \ \ \Rightarrow& \ \ \partial_{tt}(r\phi) - \partial_{rr}(r\phi) = rf(r) 
\end{align} 
where the last implication comes from multiplying both side by $r$. Set $\psi = r\phi$, then we see that $\psi$ satisfies the 1D wave equation
\begin{align}
\partial_{tt}\psi-\partial_{rr}\psi = rf(r).
\end{align}
Let us prescribe the problem with some generic conditions say
\begin{align}
&\partial_{tt}\psi-\partial_{rr}\psi = rf(r) \ \ \text{ for } r>0\\
&\psi(r, 0) = g(r) \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \psi_t(r, 0)= h(r)
\end{align}
which is just solving the 1D wave equation on the half-line. Moreover, since we have a half-line problem, we need to also specify the boundary condition at $r=0$, but for us $\psi(0, t) = 0$ since $\psi = r\phi$.

Reference: I think *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction,  Second edition* by Walter A. Strauss is an excellent text to learn basics about the linear wave equations.